# Centos server crash with too many httpd process in D state

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I have a Centos server which is running httpd, mysql, memcached and postfix.
Normally, my server load is OK

```
Usage: /usr/sbin/httpd [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
top - 07:43:55 up  9:38,  1 user,  load average: 1.04, 1.08, 1.11
Tasks: 236 total,   1 running, 234 sleeping,   0 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s):  4.2%us,  1.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 93.6%id,  1.1%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.1%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8015636k total,  5743920k used,  2271716k free,   254304k buffers
Swap:  8392696k total,        0k used,  8392696k free,  4224184k cached
```

But sometimes it crashes ( httpd is not working, can't connect ssh to server ) and I need to ask the datacenter to reboot it to be able to ssh.

After reconnecting to the server, I check with the top command and see that the server load average is still high ( more than 100 ), CPU ( wait ) is more than 70% , and there are too many httpd process in D state.

Now I'm stuck on this problem. Can anyone offer some advice?

Answer (score 2):

The process will be put in a special kind of sleep, known as "D" or "Disk Sleep". This is special, because the process can not be killed or interrupted while in such a state. This state is bad, because you can't do anything with the process in D state.  If that is happening, the very important thing is to determine where this unlucky sleep occurs. It is easy to do with ps command with l option. WCHAN column shows the name of the kernel function where the process is sleeping:

> ps axl | awk '$10 ~ /D/'

check that function with your developer

Comment: It's more commonly called 'uninterruptible sleep' - i/o is only one cause. It's a good place to start looking - the scenario described can be caused by disk errors (or bad code trying to write way too much data at a time).